# SBT 0.10.0/0.10.11 -- Potentially incompatible versions specified

Tags: sbt

I'm getting an error when running SBT, which I don't know where it originates from:

```
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/home/dcs/.sbt/plugins/)
[warn] Potentially incompatible versions specified:
[warn]    org.scala-tools.sbt: 0.10.1, 0.10.0
```

The JAR file for the sbt laucher is version's 0.10.1. The error happens even outside projects, such as when running screpl.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a build.sbt in /home/dcs/.sbt/build.properties that sets a particular sbt.version?

If not, you may have a global plugin installed that requires 0.10.0 as mentioned at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/YoXd0Tp_cjo/discussion. The solution there was to wipe the global .sbt directory (your /home/dcs/.sbt).

Comment: Right you are. The plugin `sbteclipse` required 0.10.0, though there's nothing in the file to indicate that. I updated it, which pointed to a new jar, and it the message is gone.